# What is the best way to take up as much CPU as possible using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a website for one of my friends, and as a joke I want one page to have javascript that uses as much CPU as possible. The javascript doesn't actually have to do anything, just needs to somehow make computers as slow as possible while hes on the page. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple infinite loop will already do wonders. You can top that off with spinning off a few web-workers that also do the same:

If you set `x=0n` this will use up more memory (due to BigInts allowing much larger numbers and much more memory)

```
let x=0;
while(true){
  ++x;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Keep in mind that a website by default only uses 1 thread of your CPU. Hence why web-workers to block more threads would be good. :)

You could also add a setInterval/setTimeout in the loop or other things to let the browser have time to repaint to be responsive if you want to hide it better to prevent the browser from prompting to end the unresponsive page.

Edit: You might want to consider adding some actual IO tasks (especially to the harddrive) to really slow it down.

If I remember correctly, there was a bug at one point that was being abused by downloading nearly infinite 0byte files to the host computer to essentially crash it.

---

This will hold up the CPU less than the initial infinite loop, but will leave the page responsive enough for the browser to not prompt to kill the script.

```
const wait = () => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(), 0));
async function timeWaster() {
  let x = 0n;
  while (true) {
    x++;
    if (x % 10000000n === 0n) {
      await wait();
    }
  }
}
timeWaster()
```

Comment: Modern browser will stop (or prompt to stop) non/slow-terminating execution. Now, smuggle it inside stacking setTimeout (and web workers), such that each execution “only runs for a little bit”, yet collective runs “all the time”.

Comment: It takes a bit before it does, but it should be long enough for a prank to play out, I hope :)